# partial sum of the series involving trigonometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, trigonometric-series

Let $U_r=cos(\theta +(r-1)a)$

and I have to find $f_{(r)}$ such that, $2sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})U_r=f_{(r+1)}-f_{(r)}$

I was managed to find $f_{(r)}$ such that $2sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})U_r=f_{(r+1)}-f_{(r-1)}$ where  $f_{(r)}=sin(\theta +(r-1)a)$ and $\alpha=2a$

then $f_{(r+1)}-f_{(r-1)}=sin(\theta +(r)a)-sin(\theta +(r-2)a)\\=2cos(\frac{(\theta +(r)a)+(\theta +(r-2)a)}{2})sin(\frac{(\theta +(r)a)-(\theta +(r-2)a)}{2})\\=2sin(\frac{2a}{2})cos(\theta+(r-1)a)\\=2sin(\frac{2a}{2})U_r
$

But unfortunately, how hard I tried I could not derive what they asked. I have a feeling that this problem might be wrong.

My problem is can anyone find  $f_{(r)}$ such that $2sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})U_r=f_{(r+1)}-f_{(r)}$, does such $f_{(r)}$ exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try using telescoping sum $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}(f_{r}-f_{r-1} )=f_n-f_0$$

Since you have $$f_{r}-f_{r-1} =2 \sin \left( \frac \alpha 2\right) \cos ( \theta +(r-2) \alpha) $$

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}(f_{r}-f_{r-1}) =2 \sin \left( \frac \alpha 2\right) \sum_{r=1}^{n} \cos ( \theta +(r-2) \alpha)$$

Using the formula for sum of series of cosine, with angles in airthmatic progression, we can evaluate this sum on RHS.

We get $$f_n-f_0 = 2 \sin \alpha \cos \left( \theta + \frac{(n-3)}{2} \alpha \right) \left(\frac{\sin (n \alpha / 2)}{\sin ( \alpha / 2)} \right)$$

Let $f_0 =c$, which is an arbitrary constant.

Finally, your function is $$f_n = 2 \sin \alpha \cos \left( \theta + \frac{(n-3)}{2} \alpha \right) \left(\frac{\sin (n \alpha / 2)}{\sin ( \alpha / 2)} \right)+c$$

Comment: can we find  $f_{(r)}$  such that $2sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})U_r=f_{(r+1)}-f_{(r)}$? does such $f_{(r)}$ exist?

Comment: @thomson Of course we can. See my edit.

Comment: can you tell me that explicit $f_{(r)}$?

Comment: @thomson Yes I have already written that. See the last line (I have answered in terms of $n$, you can replace $n$ with $r$). You can chose any value of $c$. It's arbitrary.

Comment: @thomson Did you see?Are there any questions still in your mind?

Comment: yes. actually, the problem here is I can't use the formula for the sum of series of cosine. rather I have to do something like my attempt in the question. I am allowed to use only basic trigonometric identities.

Comment: @thomson Then either go through the proof of this formula, or you will never get the explicit formula.